# Are there any container recycling in SF Functions computing environment?

Tags: salesforce-functions

Does anyone know (through some documentation, or webinar,..etc) if Salesforce Functions computing environment is doing "container recycling" on periodic basis? something similar to dyno recycling on Heroku [restarting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting).

This info is needed so we can know if on the developed functions we need to handle cases for random shutdown (detecting "SIGTERM" signal), or is this something managed by the platform and we don't have to worry about it?

It would be great if someone can provide some documentation or insights on how SF Functions compute environment manage resources and do the scaling.

Thanks.